# What does nautilus-data do?

Tags: nautilus, nautilus-extensions

I was searching for nautilus extensions and found nautilus-data. I couldn't find any useful result about what this plugin does. Would anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nautilus-data` isn't a plugin. The package contains some data files for Nautilus, like the Nautilus icon in various sizes and GSettings schema definitions.

It's a packages of its own because some of the files are used by other programs, too